# Use of grequests with a single request

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, grequests

I recently came across some internal code at my workplace that uses the [grequests library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) to make its HTTP requests.

However, as I was looking through the code, I noticed that the program only ever sends a single request at a time.  For instance, consider the following function:

```
def run(self, uris):
    # Create the request objects
    reqs = [grequests.get(uri) for uri in uris]

    # Send the requests out, wait for them to complete.
    results = grequests.map(reqs, size=10)
    ...
```

In all instances that call this function, only one uri is *ever* passed to the function.  In other words, all calls to this `run()` function look like:

```
run([myURI])
```

Because I am new to using grequests, would this really offer any advantage over the traditional [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library?  It would seem as though using grequests here just overcomplicates the code.

Would there ever be a case in which using grequests in this context would ever perform better than using plain old requests?

Answer (score 1):

The call to .map() blocks, so, if in practice, `uris` is always a single uri, not multiple, the function as a whole will block, and you may as well just use `requests`.